# Expo weekly notifications on Android

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm stuck on trying to make my expo app deliver push notifications every week. In docs I read that I'm supposed to use WeeklyTriggerInput interface as my trigger object but when I try to do it, I get "Failed to schedule the notification. Trigger of type: calendar is not supported on Android." error. I also can't import WeeklyTriggerInput interface from expo-notifications. Here is my code:

```
const notificationParams: Notifications.NotificationRequestInput = {
            content: {
                title: 'Just title',
                body: 'Lorem ipsum',
            },
            trigger: {
                hour: 13,
                minute: 10,
                repeats: true,
                weekday: 1,
            },
        };
        try {
            const notificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync(
                notificationParams
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By following [docs examples](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#schedulenotificationasyncnotificationrequest-notificationrequestinput-promisestring), this snippet worked for me:

```js
        const id = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            content: {
                title: "Dia de planejar sua alimentação! ",
                body: 'Utilize uma de nossas receitas, crie suas próprias, experimente novas combinações ou veja a sugestão de um nutricionista.',
            },
            trigger: {
                repeats: true,
                weekday: 1, //Sunday
                hour: 8,
                minute: 0
            },
        });
```